# Is there a way to convert a PDF to HTML / CSS using PHP?

Tags: php, css, pdf

I know solutions exist to get HTML / CSS to PDF, but is there one that works the opposite way?

I want to be able to automatically take uploaded PDFs, and turn them into HTML / CSS to be displayed on a website between a header and footer etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a command line tool, [pdf2html](http://pdftohtml.sourceforge.net/), which you could use exec() or system() in PHP to execute. Not sure it that will be ok for you?

Comment: This looks interesting... Thanks!

Comment: It is based on xPDF - http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/ so I dont know if there are docs there.